# Seeding Related Data in EF Core 3, getting error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, entity-framework-core-3.0

I followed the data seeding process explained on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding.

Used "Model seed data" method to seed related data as follows:

```
public class CaseType
{
    public int CaseTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Case> Cases { get; set; }
}

public class Case
{
    public int CaseId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public CaseType CaseType { get; set; }

    public int CaseTypeId { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<CaseType> CaseTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Case> Cases { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(
        DbContextOptions options,
        IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CaseType>().HasData(
            new CaseType {
                CaseTypeId  = 1,
                Name        = "Case Type 1",
            }
        );

        modelBuilder.Entity<Case>().HasData(
            new Case {
                CaseId      = 1,
                CaseTypeId  = 1,
                Name        = "Case 1",
                Description = "Case 1 Description",

            }
        );
    }
}
```

And gets following error when I run command: dotnet ef migrations add SeedDatabase

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 3.0.0-preview5.19227.1 initialized 'ApplicationDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite' with options: None
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.SharedTableEntryMap`1.GetMainEntry(IUpdateEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.SharedTableEntryMap`1.GetOrAddValue(IUpdateEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.DiffData(TableMapping source, TableMapping target, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Diff(TableMapping source, TableMapping target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.DiffCollection[T](IEnumerable`1 sources, IEnumerable`1 targets, DiffContext diffContext, Func`4 diff, Func`3 add, Func`3 remove, Func`4[] predicates)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

When I commented out "CaseTypeId  = 1" as shown below. Data inserted and CaseTypeId field in Cases table has value "null"

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Case>().HasData(
            new Case {
                CaseId      = 1,
                //CaseTypeId  = 1,
                Name        = "Case 1",
                Description = "Case 1 Description",

            }
        );
```

Problem is with foreign key property "CaseTypeId" in Case Entity.

So what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Problem solved. Reverted and removed some of the previous migrations and created them again. Did not change any code.

Comment: you know, you actually saved my life! Redoing migrations from scratch did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is of course not user friendly. But this is preview (beta) software, so it is not expected to work perfectly. In fact I was not able to reproduce it with 3.0.0-preview6, but then of course the update database failed with invalid foreign key reference error.

EF Core [Model seed data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#model-seed-data) has several requirements. First, you have to specify PK and FK values explicitly. Second (which is causing your issue), you have to seed *both* primary and related data.

Thus seeding the `CaseType`s with the PKs needed for seeding the `Case` FKs should solve the problem, e.g.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CaseType>().HasData(
    new CaseType
    {
        CaseTypeId = 1, // <--
        Name = "Case Type 1",
    }
);

modelBuilder.Entity<Case>().HasData(
    new Case
    {
        CaseId = 1,
        CaseTypeId = 1, // <--
        Name = "Case 1",
        Description = "Case 1 Description",
    },
    new Case
    {
        CaseId = 2,
        CaseTypeId = 1, // <--
        Name = "Case 2",
        Description = "Case 2 Description",
    }
);
```